# .height() only making DIV scrollable after window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

The intent of this script is to make a DIV that is 100% of the page height minus the top section.

Here's the page:

http://nerdi.net/playground/kev/indexNEW.html

Here it is stripped down on jsFiddle, where it appears to be working.

http://jsfiddle.net/JVKbR/94/

For me, (on Chrome and FF) the scrollable div (.mid-col-main) only becomes scrollable upon resizing the window (Maximize, drag from corner, etc)

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT: Jasper and Davin's solution both work. Thank you.**

Comment: You can easily workaround this with a simple `$(window).resize()` if you, like me, couldn't be bothered figuring this out.

Comment: No it isn't. Your version doesn't work, because it doesn't actually wait for the page load, you're executing the code immediately. And that obviously won't work, because the DOM isn't ready. You need to change that to `window.onload=function(){ $(window).resize(); };`

Comment: Wow I'm retarded, that fixed it. Playing with too many versions. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the DOM to be ready, basically you were running the code too soon and `div.mid-col-main` is not available yet:

```
$(function () {
    var midColTopHeight = $("div.mid-col-top").height(),
        $window         = $(window),
        $midColMain     = $('div.mid-col-main');
    $window.resize(function(){
        $midColMain.height(($window.height() - midColTopHeight));
    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Here I have placed your binding code inside a `document.ready` event handler and also triggered a `resize` event on the `window` element. I also optimized your code a bit to cache things that don't change (you don't need to select the same element every `resize` event).

Instead of running this code in a `document.ready` event handler, you could put this code at the end of the HTML document (just before the closing `</body>` tag), that way the element you want to target will be available.

Comment: Thank you. @davin 's solution in the OP comments worked as well but this looks cleaner. Much appreciated.